# Utility to demand function

Tags: economics

Suppose that Sally’s preferences over baskets containing food (good x), and clothing (good y), are described by the utility function U(x,y)=√x+y

Sally’s corresponding marginal utilities are,

Ux=$1\over2√x$
and Uy=$1$

Use Px to represent the price of food, Py to represent the price of clothing, and I to represent Sally’s income.

```
    Question 1: Find Sally's food demand function, and Sally's clothing demand function. For the purposes of this question you should assume that I/Py greater than or equal Py/4Px.
```

Even by using the I=Py(y)+Px(x) formula, I tried using $MUx\over MUy$=$Px\over Py$ and letting one of the price be 1. But I am unable to substitute into the income function as I could find y value.

Comment: I don't know how to read your utility function.  Did you mean $x + \sqrt y$?  Please see the help for MathJax suggestions for formatting.

Comment: Hi Ross, I edited my question. is it better?